# Catching exception errors when logging in via NodeJS + MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, exception, connection

Recently I've been trying to learn NodeJS to set up a log in process, so I decided to write all the errors and make exceptions for them. My question is how can I make sure each if is responsible for each error code. I haven't worked with try and catch before so this is a new territory for me.
Also is it better to use multiple try-catch or should I consider using 1 block where I can use a switch for example (used else if here as a quick example).

- > Table with Status errors

0 - no connection with database.

1 - connection ok but we dont have any privileges for access to the
   database or something like that.

2 - all ok.

3 - ok, but no data found in query results.

4 - error getting results of query.

5 - other.

```
module.exports = (username,password,connection ) => {
var data ={
    "Status" : null,
    "Data"   : {} //JSON results inside of Data Json 

}

try{
    connection.query("SELECT id FROM players", function (error, results, fields) {

        if (error){




            data.Status = 0;
            data.Data= "No connection can be established with the database";
            return data
        }

        else if(error){

            data.Status = 1;  
            data.Data= results + "Connection OK but no priviliges";
            return data
        }

        else if(error){

            data.Status = 2;  
            data.Data=results + "connection running";
            return data
        }

        else if(error){

            data.Status = 3;  
            data.Data=results + "No data found in query results";
            return data
        }

        else if(error){

            data.Status = 4; 
            data.Data=results;
            return data
        }

        else if(error){

            data.Status = 5;  
            data.Data=results;
            return data
        }


      });
}


catch(e){

    console.log(e);

    data.Status= 2;
    data.Data=null;
    return data;

}


};
```

Comment: Pushing errors to a browser is a bit of a waste, the user can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to async programming, your try/catch block won't do anything for any I/O process, all errors are handled by `error` object in the callback function. (unless you use the last async/await ES6 pattern)

```
connection.query("SELECT id FROM players", function (error, results, fields) {
  if (!error) { // no error, return results
    data.status = 2;
    data.Data = results;
    return data;
  }
  // for all error code, please check mysql library document
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#error-handling
  if (error.code === 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR') {
    data.Status = 1; 
    data.Data=results;
    return data
  }

  // handle any other error codes
  // if ....
});
```

Edit: please note that, your exported function in `module.exports` won't return anything because you are calling database query which is an async I/O process and requires another callback function to get the data returned by database

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as expected :

```
if (error){
  console.log("I'm the error");
  return;
} else if(error){
  console.log("I will never be display on error because of return in the first if");
}
```

Should be :

```
if (!error){
    // No error
} else if(error === 'something'){
    // Error something
} else if ....
    // Other type of error
} else {
    // Unknown error
}
```

You can use a switch instead in a more elegant way :

```
const data = { Status: 1, Data: results }

if(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
     case 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' :
        data.Satus = 2;
        return data;
     ...
  }
}

return data;
```